# Remove first whitespace in regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

Im newbie in regex so I need help how to remove first whitespace in regex in each row in notepad++?

Example : 
 
 191.341.411.314 80
 
 191.341.411.315 80
 
 191.341.411.316 80
 
 191.341.411.317 80

and I need this
 
191.341.411.314 80
 
191.341.411.315 80
 
191.341.411.316 80
 
191.341.411.317 80

list include +1000 lines what is a best solution??

Comment: I wouldn't use a regex for that, I'd just trim the string

Comment: Is the whitespace in the regex or in the string you're matching with the regex?

Comment: which language are you working on ?

Comment: Ops new problema again :S

Comment: Where is your new problem? My solution is in Notepad++ also working 100000 lines, just press replace all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) your regex to the start of the string

```
^\s
```

and replace with nothing. `\s` is a [shorthand character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for whitespace

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com/v1?38ktn)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first whitespace you have to gsub the string you are having like so:

```
" 191.341.411.314 80".gsub(/^\p{Space}/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YU9vf/4/)**</kbd>

#### RegExp

```
/^\s/         // remove only first whitespace

/\s/          // remove first whitespace entire string
/ /           // remove first whitespace entire string
```

#### Code

```
var finalUrl = " 191.341.411.314 80";

console.log(finalUrl);                                // Before
console.log(finalUrl.replace(/^\s/ , ''));            // After
```

#### Result

```
 191.341.411.314 80
191.341.411.314 80
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: this will remove the space between `4` and `8` also.

Comment: Sorry @aelor its my mistake to add \g end but now check its clearly work.

Comment: but still its better to make it ^\s beacuse in places where there is nos space at the beginning , it will remove the second whitespace

Comment: ok ok i got this expression its work fine ok i add in my question thank you

Answer (score 0):

After your update its clear that you have a file with these lines.

In that case its better to do something like this :

the `awk` way

```
awk '{print $1" "$2}' text.txt
```

where text.txt will be the file containing your initial text. you can write out the result in a different file using this:

```
awk '{print $1" "$2}' text.txt > finaltext.txt
```

or the `perl` way

```
perl -pe 's/^\s//g' text
```

=========

```
var str = " 191.341.411.314 80"; //with a space at beginning
console.log(str);
var res = str.replace(/^\s?/, '');
console.log(res);
```

try this in your firebug console.

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=\s).*` will select everything that follows a single whitespace character. However, it will not match to the strings that doesn't start with a whitespace.

Anyway, wouldn't simply trimming the string solve your problem? For this use case regex seems to be a bit of overkill to me.